How to prevent image blurring/flashing while moving?
I've recently created a camera which follows the player around the map. The camera centers the player in the middle and can zoom in and out with CTRL+Scroll wheel.
camera_handler.py:
import pygame

class CameraHandler:
    camera_x, camera_y = 0, 0
    zoom_scale = 1.0

    @staticmethod
    def update_camera_coords(player_rect):
        width, height = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size() 
        CameraHandler.camera_x = min(player_rect.centerx - width // 2, width * 2 - width)
        CameraHandler.camera_y = min(player_rect.centery - height // 2, height * 2 - height)

    def handle_camera_event(event):
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEWHEEL and pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_CTRL:
            if event.y == 1:
                CameraHandler.zoom_scale = max(CameraHandler.zoom_scale - 0.2, 0.5)
            elif event.y == -1:
                CameraHandler.zoom_scale = min(CameraHandler.zoom_scale + 0.2, 2.5)
        
    @staticmethod
    def get_camera_surface(sprite_group):
        camera_surface_size = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()
        camera_surface = pygame.Surface(camera_surface_size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
        camera_surface_size_vector = pygame.math.Vector2(camera_surface_size)
        camera_surface.fill((129, 167, 69))  

        offset_x = -CameraHandler.camera_x
        offset_y = -CameraHandler.camera_y

        for sprite in sprite_group:
            camera_surface.blit(sprite.image, (sprite.rect.x + offset_x, sprite.rect.y + offset_y))

        scaled_surface = pygame.transform.scale(camera_surface, camera_surface_size_vector * CameraHandler.zoom_scale)
        centered_rect = scaled_surface.get_rect(center=(camera_surface_size[0] // 2, camera_surface_size[1] // 2))
        return scaled_surface, centered_rect

I blit the result of the get_camera_surface() onto the main screen in my game loop:
    def main(self):
        while self.playing:
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()
            self.dt = self.clock.tick(self.framerate) / 1000
        self.running = False

    def draw(self):
        camera_surface, rect = CameraHandler.get_camera_surface(self.all_sprites)
        self.screen.blit(camera_surface, rect) 
        pygame.display.update(rect)

When I zoom out, and move around the map in the x-axis direction, all sprites have this weird flickering effect, when you look closely it looks like a white wave. How do I fix this?

I've tried to set the screen flag to pygame.DOUBLEBUF but I haven't noticed any changes. I tried using .flip() instead of update() but there is also no change.

The AI suggests to "Instead of creating a new surface for the camera in every frame, you should create a dedicated background surface that remains constant through updates, and then draw it on top of the camera surface. ". Does that help you?

Thank you, kind person! I've done this and the issue was fixed. However, this is a temporary solution. Walls must have "health" points and upon taking damage they will change their appearance. Therefore they must eventually be updated. But, thank you, nonetheless.

You are welcome! though, why would the texture change cause a problem? You should still be able to use the same surface

for sprite in sprite_group:           if sprite.hp> 200:                screen.blit(sprite.image_full_hp, (sprite.rect.x + offset_x, sprite.rect.y + offset_y))
(Unsure whether I took the right part of the code or not)

Oh, I presumed this static background is drawn only once and it does not change. This static background is suitable for static objects like the ground which doesn't change throughout the game. However, walls aren't meant to be truly static, they must change they appearance when they receive damage to reflect how close they are to being destroyed. This means the static background must be redrawn, which means it isn't truly static.

This is my current implementation for creating a static background (this method is only called once before the start of the game): `@staticmethod
def render_static_objects(static_objects, world_size):
# Create a static world surface once
if CameraHandler.static_world_surface is None:
CameraHandler.static_world_surface = pygame.Surface(world_size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
CameraHandler.static_world_surface.fill((129, 167, 69))
        for obj in static_objects:
            CameraHandler.static_world_surface.blit(obj.image, obj.rect)`


what do you think of this?
def draw_bg_with_updated_wall(CameraHandler x, y, hp):  image = find_image(hp, "wall")  CameraHandler.static_world_surface.blit(image, (x, y))

Wow! This is perfect. Instead of updating the whole static background it updates a part of it. I'll use this, thank you!

I added an answer with basically what we said here. Good luck!

The issue with your code is that you recreate the surface for the camera in every frame instead of simply reusing the same.
To make single thing change on that map based on the actions of the player you can simply overlap a piece of the map with another shape / texture, like in the case of the walls that take damage. Here is how a function that does what I just said could be structured:
def draw_bg_with_updated_wall(CameraHandler x, y, hp):  
    image = find_image(hp, "wall")   
    CameraHandler.static_world_surface.blit(image, (x, y))

where find_image is just a function that gives you the corresponding texture of the wall

My answer seems correct, so I do not see why it was downvoted
